# Cannot get email header image to scale

Tags: html, css, html-email, email-client

I am trying to use an inline style

The template is simple and is responsive in the browser but is not when I send it to my phone. The image runs off the page and does not scale to the viewport.

Here is the code:

In the img tag I put an inline style.

```
style="display:block; width:auto; height:100%:"
```

Where am I going wrong?

I am sending it to an android phone using gmail. Here is the ENTIRE page:

```
!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/> <meta charset="utf-8" /> <title>Best Holiday Wishes</title> </head> <body> <!-- Begin Content --> <div style="width:100%; height:auto; margin:0 auto;"> <img src="literacy2pointzero.com/images/03.jpg"; style="display:block; width:auto; height:100%:" alt="Holiday Wishes" /> </div> <!-- End Content --> </body> </html>
```

Comment: We are going to need all of the code. We can't do anything with this.

Comment: Which phone and which email client? They all handle html/css differently.

Comment: I am sending it to an android phone using gmail.

Here is the ENTIRE page

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Best Holiday Wishes</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Begin Content -->
<div style="width:100%; height:auto; margin:0 auto;">
<img src="http://www.literacy2pointzero.com/images/03.jpg" style="display:block; width:auto; height:100%:" alt="Holiday Wishes" />
</div>
<!-- End Content -->
</body>
</html>

Comment: @user2683415 - you should update your question with the pertinent details. Comment section is not suited for these types of updates.

Comment: Bear in mind that the mail software & webmail doesn't always support all the CSS features.

Comment: How are you sending the HTML code from gmail when it doesnt have a native 'insert HTML' editor only a WYSIWYG? The way you are inserting the email may also be affecting how the coding is being handled.  Also, width:auto is pretty much useless in emails and height styling is pretty much more of a detriment than a help in email. Your best bet is to use media queries and change the image to defined values.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving these properties.

Style="Max-width:100%;width:100%\9;height: auto;"

It will make the image shrink and resize to its max size.

Comment: I tried but the same result. For some reason android does not seem to apply inline styles to an image.

Comment: What does the \9 hack do?

Comment: Sorry... That wasn't needed.. ! But its for IE. Only IE less than 9 will read that property, rest will ignore it.

Comment: Can u create a fiddle of ur question.? Then we may can see.. What exactly is going wrong..

Comment: The trouble is it works perfectly in Fiferfox when I test it for mobile GRRRRR

Comment: whats the semi-colon just after your img src tag end - just before starting style ? It wont be reading the the style properties after ; !!! Is it there in ur original code also ? Im not talking about ur fiddle, but about your code, you commented after ur question

Answer (score 0):

try this with your image

`<img src="http://www.literacy2pointzero.com/images/03.jpg" style="max-width:100%; height: auto;" width="100%" height="auto" alt="Holiday Wishes" />`

but the problem might be your viewport tag. Try this one:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,  user-scalable=no"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Without more info, below is best I can do.  It is based off a similar issue in Outlook.  It may not work though depending on how your sending email client renders the width property of an image (e.g. Outlook removes percentages and creates a defined value regardless of what you have in the HTML).

First - use a table, it is more stable in email clients. Second by having 3 columns with a defined middle one, you are able to fake the CSS max-width style allowing it to shrink to screen size, but never go past what was defined in the TD tag. ALSO make sure to add the full URL when referencing src or href in emails.

See below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Best Holiday Wishes</title>
</head>
<body> <!-- Begin Content --> <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td></td>
<td width="600" align="center"><img width="100%" src="http://www.literacy2pointzero.com/images/03.jpg"; style="display:block;" alt="Holiday Wishes" /></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table> <!-- End Content --> </body> </html>
```